# Auto filing names of a City if the Country name is given

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I am working on a site which prvides location based searching of users i.e. user  can query system like "Give me the list of users staying at locality, city" and the system responds with the list of user names.

For that I want to provide user one combo box to select the country name and a text box to type in the few letters of City name, based on the text in the text box the system suggests the city names, i.e. for letter 'A' the system suggests all city names containing letter 'A', and the results are filtered thereafter.

I have searched for a while now few recommend storing data in my server, few recommend using a web service, api or something like that. I dont want to store data in my server since storing lacs of frequently changing data is nt a wise option, and if I go for third party api, library or service how to provide autofill feature on that....

Please suggest me some ways to accomplish this task,

Thanks in advance,

**EDIT**
After researching on various possible solutions I finally decided to use [geo-autoComplete](http://code.google.com/p/geo-autocomplete/) api from Google, Fortunately the documentation helped me to develop a working demo very fast.

However it faiils in restricting the suggestions to some specific Region/ Country, `Autocomplete (google.maps.places.Autocomplete)` class has a method `setBounds(LatLngBounds)` which can be used to filter the suggestions, How can I get the LatLngBounds object from LatLng object ? and How can I increase the number of suggestions given by auto complete ? **plz help....**

Comment: Currently I am working with this http://code.google.com/p/geo-autocomplete/ please suggest me if there is some other even better solution available..... Will post it as answer if wont get any other from the community....

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

http://bassistance.de/2009/03/03/jquery-snippet-autocomplete-city-based-on-zip-code/

Or you can make a custom one with jQuery UI AutoComplete
http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote

Comment: thanks for the link, bt my requirements are kind of differrent I want to use this feature in user search page and searching a user based on city is far more convenient than by pincode... any ways thanks..

Comment: @amit: like he said in the answer: you can make a custom one with jQuery UI AutoComplete ;)

Comment: You can use jQuery UI to query a remote server based on a search term (the city) and have the server respond with a json object of the cities that match it (for the auto complete feature) and then on select you can ajax a query to select all users from that city

Comment: @Adam I think u have misunderstood the original question, I want a mechanism to get the city data, to auto fill my text boxes....for after wards processing I may use plain JavaScript or jQuery...